# C# Setting a size of an array that has no constant size

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two arrays. The first array is a set of integers inputted by the user. The second array has no constant size, it is dependent on how many times an inputted number exists in the first array. The program searches through the first array and it inserts the index of the matched number into the second array.

So for example if the number 3 appears 5 times in the first array, the size of the second array will be 5.

Here is a snippet of code just containing the search. Array arr is set by the user.

```
        int[] pos = new int[?];
        int z = 0;
        Console.Write("Now enter a number to compare: ");
        int c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length-1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] == c)
            {   
               pos[z] = j;
                z++;
            }
        }
```

I'm sure there is a very simple solution that I'm overlooking. I can't have any empty values in the second array or it will mess up the rest of my program and the size has to be exactly equal to the number of times the number is found.

Comment: Not really sure about your question, but if you are looking for an array with dynamic size, then consider `List<T>`

Comment: why don't you use a `list`?

Comment: @ironzionlion: It's probably homework.  Some goofy assignment to teach how to use arrays.

Comment: Sounds like school project.  Maybe describe actual assignment and someone can give you a hint.

Comment: you can resize array wile preserving old values by using the **Array.Resize(ref pos, NewSizeInteger);** see msdn [Array.Resize(T) Method (System)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22SYSTEM.ARRAY.RESIZE%60%601%22%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

Comment: @Adam47: this is not homework or assignment. I'm trying to teach myself C# using the limited programming knowledge I have. Thanks for the answers though.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in .NET have a fixed size. The only way to "resize" an array is to create a new array of the right size, copy over all the existing items, and keep using the new array instead of the old.

Or... you can use one of the dynamic collection types in .NET, such as [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx).

You declare it like this:

```
List<int> pos = new List<int>();
```

and you add another item to it by calling its Add method:

```
pos.Add(j);
```

If at the end you still require it as an array, you can call `.ToArray()` on the list to get back an array that has the right size to contain all the elements of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<int>.
```

You can add items using

```
list.add(123)
```

The when you need an array at the end, you can call

```
var array = list.ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
List<T>
```

instead of an array

I believe this is the best option for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Sets the size of the second array with the same size of the first, as it is to compare the arrays should be equal in size, as well as look for the same size:

```
int[] pos = new int[arr.Length];
```

Comment: He is not actually comparing the arrays. The desired array will have one entry for each time a given number appears in the given array.

Comment: Create a list or an ArrayList and so you use as if it were an object: put this using System.Collections; and then in your code (ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();) and for add new items you use (arr.add(Obj));

Comment: You should update your answer rather than putting new ideas in comments. I believe that even at low rep you can always edit your own answers. You might also want to look at other people's answers who have suggested using `List<int>` which in some ways is similar to an ArrayList except that it is generic and thus you can have the advantage of type safety and know you are only ever going to add ints to your collection because the compiler would object otherwise. :)